# Generators of SL_n of a local ring of integers.

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [Generators of $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ and $GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201044/generators-of-gl-n-bbb-z-and-gl-n-bbb-z-p)

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers in a characteristic zero non-archimedean local field $K$.

What is the minimal number of topological generators of $SL_n(\mathcal{O}_K)$?

In particular, is this number bounded independent of $n$? Independent of $K$? I'd also be interested in any information when $K$ is a number field, as well.