# is automorphism group finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ - $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ finitely generated?
What are the best sources to read about its properties? (including large scale ones)

Comment: **Hint:** Elementary matrices

Comment: There are several answers on MSE here, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201044/generators-of-gl-n-bbb-z-and-gl-n-bbb-z-p/201553). Also on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181366/minimal-number-of-generators-for-gln-mathbbz).